# Reduce the hot taste in a Cambodian curry

Tags: cream, curry, spicy-hot

I made a Cambodian curry, but it was too hot! They say dairy is good for cooling hot curries, but this one I made has coconut milk in it. Would it be ok to put cream in it? If so, single or double??

Answer (score 3):

If it is about keeping authenticity, more coconut milk would be the answer. If you just want a toned down but well tasting curry, any emulsified fat - coconut milk, cream, yoghurt - will do, as long as you add it carefully in a way that doesn't make it split and become grainy (so whisk it, add it carefully with the heat turned off). Cream and/or yoghurt would be the authentic addition for a north indian curry.

Comment: This is the best answer, just be sure to evaporate the excess liquid from the milk (etc.) too.

Comment: I do wonder whether I should have added "...not mayonnaise, of course..." after "any emulsified fat" :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't add anything to the curry itself.

Instead, serve it over steamed rice. The starchy rice will do more to dilute the hot pepper flavor than any liquid you would add to the curry.